# redirect NDR messages with Exchange 2010

Tags: email, exchange-2010

For one Exchange mailbox, I want to manage non-delivery notifications as follows

- redirect to a remote mailbox
- move to a specific folder

To do so, I created a rule from within Outlook:

> Upon receiving a message with "postmaster@" or "Mailer-Daemon@" in the sender address, redirect it to "foobar@remote.example.com" and move it to "myfolder"

However, this works only partially:

- If Exchange can relay to our firewall, but then the firewall cannot relay the mail further, our firewall sends back as "Mailer-Daemon@firewall.example.com"; this matches the rule. As expected, the mail is both forwarded to "foobar@remote.example.com" and moved to "myfolder"
- If Exchange can relay to our firewall, and the firewall can relay successfully to the receivers MX, but some problem occurs afterwards, the corresponding mail server sends back a message as "postmaster@receiving-domain.com". This should trigger - and apparently does (I can see this because the message is moved to "myfolder"), but the redirection to "foobar@remote.example.com" does not happen

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

In order to forward emails to an external recipient you should create first a mail enabled contact with the external email address and then make sure you exchange transport settings allow to forward emails. By default exchange is not allowing that. Check the Settings on Organization Config - Hub Transport - Remote Domains - Default - Message Format - "Allow automatic forwards". Also Check the NDR Message you get if it comes from your exchange server or the receiving one.

[image: Forwarding Transport Settings]

Comment: If you are forwarding with a contact at the mailbox level then you don't need to enable Allow Automatic Forward. That also isn't a recommended setting as it allows anyone in the business to forward emails to an external mailbox using Outlook rules, which can mean data loss is easy.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use rules on most types of NDRs within Outlook. That is because they are system messages. Therefore whatever you try to do is going to be unreliable or simply fail to work, and therefore you need to find some other way to manage those NDRs.

Some are working because Exchange/Outlook is probably not recognising them as NDRs. If you have a "Send Again" button on the email then it is seen as an NDR.

Answer (score 0):

You can only set it for all users:

- `Set-OrganizationConfig -MicrosoftExchangeRecipientReplyRecipient <MailboxIdentity>`
- By default, even though there are no enhanced status codes specified, NDRs for these codes are automatically sent to the Exchange recipient:

5.1.4
5.2.0
5.2.4
5.4.4
5.4.6
5.4.8